Google Sheets ownership rights change situation
I have a google sheet in a shared company drive. The owner of the sheet is no longer with the company and it appears there is no longer an "owner". However, we use this platform that can link google sheets for data usage and you can just sync every so often to update the data that is being pulled. It is saying that because that user is no longer active no one can sync that sheet. Is there a way to get the ownership rights to that sheet somehow?
I tried contacting support of the service we use that pulls those sheets and they said we need to contact Google to have them reassign ownership rights

There are two scenarios here. If the file is inside a Shared Drive, that means the file belongs to the shared drive itself, therefore it doesn't matter that the user who created it is not in the organization anymore, the file will remain in the shared drive and there is no need to make changes to the ownership as long as you or anyone who needs access to it is a member of the Shared Drive.
If you really need to have ownership of that file, then ask the Super Admin to contact Google Workspace support to track the specific Shared Drive the file is in, and then either add you to the Shared Drive with "Manager" access and then you can take the file. [1]
The super admin could also take ownership of the file alone, and then transfer ownership of that file to you, but that might mess up the permissions to access the file, so if the file is in a shared drive and nobody has lost access to it, you can just keep it that way.
[1] https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799
